# Using Custom Basemaps with BasemapToggle widget

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, basemap

I'm trying to upgrade my app from version 3.3 to version 3.7 of the ArcGIS JavaScript API and am switching out the basemap gallery for the new BasemapToggle widget.

I have two custom basemaps that I want to use in my app using [BasemapToggle](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/widget_toggle.html).

Is this possible?

The [API homepage](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jshelp/whats_new.html) suggests it is but I haven't seen a sample or any documentation on how to do it properly.

Can anybody point me towards a solution or example of how to use my own basemaps with this widget?

I'm trying to do this with two basemaps, loading one of them as the initial basemap and then being able to toggle between them. My attempt at Derek's answer is [HERE](http://jsbin.com/iFakeLa/4/)

Comment: Adding a comment here so you can check out my edited answer below showing how to use a custom basemap with the basemap toggle.

Comment: @DerekSwingley thanks again. I've been trying it out so that it uses 2 custom basemaps and loads one of them from the start as well. No luck yet but I'm sure I'll get there.

Comment: edit your question to include your code or the URLs for the services you want to use? Maybe I can sort it out for you.

Comment: @DerekSwingley Please see my edit above. Thanks for the help.

Comment: try this:  http://jsbin.com/iFakeLa/5/

Comment: thanks! looks great. Of course when I try and import it into my app it gives a map error. I love programming! thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The BasemapToggle can only use basemaps from arcgis.com. I'll get the text on the page you referenced updated, it shouldn't say you can use your own custom basemaps. I apologize for the mistake.

It is possible to use custom maps with the basemap toggle, but it takes a little work. First, load the default API config object and put info for your basemaps on esriConfig.defaults.map.basemaps:

```
require([
  "esri/map", 
  "esri/dijit/BasemapToggle", 
  "esri/config",
  "dojo/domReady!"
], function(
  Map, BasemapToggle, esriConfig
)  {
  console.log(esriConfig.defaults.map.basemaps);
  esriConfig.defaults.map.basemaps.delorme = {
    baseMapLayers: [
      { url: "http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Specialty/DeLorme_World_Base_Map/MapServer" }
    ],
    title: "Delorme"
  };
```

Then specify both basemap and basemaps when you create the toggle:

```
toggle = new BasemapToggle({
  map: map,
  basemap: "delorme",
  basemaps: {
    delorme: {
      label: "delorme",
      url: "http://www.delorme.com/images/homepage/dbm_icon.jpg"
    }, topo: {
      label: "topo",
      url: "http://js.arcgis.com/3.7/js/esri/dijit/images/basemaps/topo.jpg"
    }
  }
}, "BasemapToggle");
toggle.startup();
```

Working page on jsbin:  http://jsbin.com/iFakeLa/1

Comment: Sounds like a prime item for a enhancement; we were looking at that ourselves...

Comment: Thanks Derek. Perhaps this could get worked into the next update.

Comment: @D.E.Wright updated to show an example of how to customize the widget to use custom maps

Comment: see [my answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/197512/3112) below for an update for newer versions of the JS API

Answer (score 2):

It appears that Derek's answer above no longer works at version 3.16 of the JS API.

An update came from Kelly Hutchins at Esri, and is to add the custom basemap to `esri/basemaps` as shown at https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/esri.basemaps-amd.html

```
require([
    "esri/basemaps",
    "esri/map",
    "dojo/domReady!"
  ], function (esriBasemaps, Map){
    esriBasemaps.delorme = {
      baseMapLayers: [{url: "https://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Specialty/DeLorme_World_Base_Map/MapServer"}],
      thumbnailUrl: "https://www.example.com/images/thumbnail_2014-11-25_61051.png",
      title: "Delorme"
    };

    var map = new Map("ui-map", {
      basemap: "delorme",
      center: [-111.879655861, 40.571338776], // long, lat
      zoom: 13,
      sliderStyle: "small"
    });
});
```

Once the custom basemap has been added to `esri/basemaps` it can be used in the basemapToggle in the same manner as a default basemap:

```
    var toggle = new BasemapToggle({
      map: map,
      basemap: "satellite",
      basemaps:
        {
        "delorme":{
          "title":"delorme",
          "thumbnailUrl":"https://www.example.com/images/thumbnail_2014-11-25_61051.png"
        },
        "satellite":{
          "title":"satellite",
          "thumbnailUrl":"https://js.arcgis.com/3.15/esri/images/basemap/satellite.jpg"
        }
      }

    }, "BasemapToggle");
    toggle.startup();
```