# ArcGIS JavaScript Map loads but doesn't display

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, basemap

I just started creating a very simple mobile GIS app using ArcGIS JavaScript API, and I am experiencing a very peculiar issue.

When the app loads, the basemap is white (not visible) until you use the zoom control.  After that, the app works except for the BasemapToggle control.  I was using another similar post as a template to add a custom basemap to the BasemapToggle control seen here:

[How to Use Custom Basemaps with BasemapToggle widget?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74154/how-to-use-custom-basemaps-with-basemaptoggle-widget)

There are no errors reporting, so I am not sure what is causing both the fault basemap load and the BasemapToggle issue.

Has anyone else experienced this and have information on resolving the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the value you're passing for `basemap` in the `BasemapToggle` constructor from:

```
basemap: 'Local',
```

to:

```
basemap: 'local'
```

(i.e. a lowercase 'L').  Then it'll render right off the bat.  I think the value has to match exactly with the thing you put into `esriConfig.defaults.map.basemaps`.